# Splitting Text file entries to add into arraylists

Tags: java

I usually use this site when I'm stuck, but currently I can't find a solution for my problem so I'll try asking a question. Sorry if it might be easy to work around but I've been trying for hours now and can't proceed.

I got a text file with the list below:

```
1,John,Spiteri,99845124,10/05/2018,2
2,Kate,Galea,79451245,10/05/2018,4,Highchair required
1,Peter,Zahra,79845731,21/07/2018,3
3,Alice,Carabott,99468791,10/05/2018,10
4,James,Dingli,99364125,10/05/2018,15,Birthday
2,Kim,Fenech,99871632,21/07/2018,4,Cake Ordered
5,George,Pace,79541247,10/05/2018,2,Vegetarian Menu
3,Jack,Vella,99451785,21/07/2018,2
```

Now, I have to store each specific value into it's own arraylist. That is easy, just do an enhanced forloop using a variable holding the data split by the commas. Each line is it's own reservation. Comments are optional so not all have one. This makes using split a pain as I have to check manually and if there's nothing I add an empty string value in the arraylist.

Currently my idea (Might be bad) was to use a variable which counted till 7, then reset to add it's specific value in each arraylist. However I have a problem when I reach the last value in the first line. For some reason, when the number 2 is reached, even tough they're shown separate, I keep getting an error NumberFormatException. Also my if statement to check if there's a comment or not is not working.

I'll post the method below. If there's anyone that can lend a hand, I'd appreciate it :) I don't mind just explanation, I'm here to learn not to cheat. Thanks.

```
ArrayList<Integer> tableNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>(); // To be changed!!!
ArrayList<Integer> quantities = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

int counter = 0;
String[] bookList = bookings.split(",");

for(String element: bookList){
    counter++;
    System.out.println(element);

    if(counter == 1)
        tableNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(element));
    if(counter == 2)
        names.add(element);
    if(counter == 3)
        surnames.add(element);
    if(counter == 4)
        contacts.add(element);
    if(counter == 5)
        dates.add(element);
    if(counter == 6)
        quantities.add(Integer.parseInt(element)); // Line 86
    if(counter == 7){
        char comment = element.charAt(0);

        if(element.length() < 2 && Character.isDigit(comment)){
            comments.add(" "); 
            tableNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(element));
            counter = 1;
        }    
        else {
            comments.add(element);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 
2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at bistronomic.restaurant.Main.loadBookings(Main.java:86)
        at bistronomic.restaurant.Main.<init>(Main.java:108)
        at bistronomic.restaurant.Main$7.run(Main.java:387)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the declarations for the variables names, contacts, dates, etc?

Comment: Added arraylist initialization.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Are you sure the error isn't being thrown on the tableNumbers.add(...) line? It might help to post the whole error message and indicate which line exactly it refers to.

Comment: Added the error in the first post.

Main.java:86 Is the quantities line.

Comment: You say it occurs "when the number 2 is reached" so please update that. Also, add a little comment or something to clearly show which line the error is thrown on.

Comment: Why would you erase the whole question text after its been solved?

Comment: You can't, it's part of stackoverflow now.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. You licensed your content to Stack Overflow when you posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void loadBookings() {

    String bookings = FileIO.readTextFile("bookings.txt");
    //GregorianCalendar cal1;
    //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    int counter = 0;
    String[] bookList = bookings.split(",");

    for (String element : bookList) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Element to be persed:" + element);

        if (counter == 1) {
            tableNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(element.trim()));
        } else if (counter == 2) {
            names.add(element);
        } else if (counter == 3) {
            surnames.add(element);
        } else if (counter == 4) {
            contacts.add(element);
        } else if (counter == 5) {
            dates.add(element);
        } else if (counter == 6 || counter == 7) {

            if (element.contains("\n")) {
                String thisLineLastElement = "";
                String nextLineFirstElement = "";

                if (element.endsWith("\n")) {
                    thisLineLastElement = element.trim();
                } else {
                    String[] split = element.split("\n");
                    thisLineLastElement = split[0];
                    nextLineFirstElement = split[1];
                }

                if (counter == 6) {
                    quantities.add(Integer.parseInt(thisLineLastElement.trim()));
                    comments.add("N/a");

                } else if (counter == 7) {
                    comments.add(thisLineLastElement);
                }
                if (!element.endsWith("\n")) {
                    tableNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(nextLineFirstElement.trim()));
                }
                counter = 1;
            }

            if (counter == 6) {
                quantities.add(Integer.parseInt(element.trim()));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

chech this out.

Comment: Hi RJMIMI38, forgive me but could your solution be edited out? Apparently some students found out about this page, and someone told the teachers. 

They asked me to remove the question entirely but I can't do that so this would suffice.

Thanks and sorry for asking this.

Comment: Dodmsayer it would be better if you delete the post. Editing the answer would be misleading. Thanks

Comment: Sadly I can't. There's up-votes on certain answers and my main question.

Comment: I appreciate it. My apologies for all of this, don't know why any student would mindlessly shill this to lecturers. It boggles my mind. I didn't come to cheat, I asked to understand the issue and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

try this I just change the way you loop to make it easier to access you can change the file access to String [], if I understand Question correctly this should solve the problem

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> tableNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>(); // To be changed!!!
        ArrayList<Integer> quantities = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  // till here each line alone

                String dataEachLine[] = line.split(",");

                tableNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(dataEachLine[0]));
                names.add(dataEachLine[1]);
                surnames.add(dataEachLine[2]);
                contacts.add(dataEachLine[3]);
                dates.add(dataEachLine[4]);
                quantities.add(Integer.parseInt(dataEachLine[5]));
                if (dataEachLine.length > 6) {
                    comments.add(dataEachLine[6]);

                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm currently calling another script which handles the text file. I'll check it out tough, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

if(counter == 6)
          quantities.add(Integer.parseInt(element.trim()));

Comment: please upload the input file

Comment: Uploaded file in original post. I'm using netbeans and jframe just fyi.

Comment: Your input system has a problem. Your method has no problem. You are taking the file as a single string.Thus end of line is not working. It is taking last 2 of first line and first 2 of 2nd line as an element. Which is becoming '2 2' . Best way to escape this problem is to use BufferedReader.

Comment: The assignment required us to return a string heh :/

That is the sole reason I made it like that.

Comment: Then you can split them by space

Comment: If you're saying to edit the text file and have spaces instead of commas, I can't do that. We're not allowed to edit the text file.